# How to unit test database methods in C#?

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing

I've searched everywhere, but nothing I found was applicable to my current situation.

I have a class that helps with DB connections, and I need to unit test some of its methods:

```
public class DBHelper
{
        private SqlConnection conn;
        private SqlCommand textCommand;

        public DBHelper(IDbConnection connection)
        {
            conn = (SqlConnection)connection;
            textCommand = new SqlCommand();
            textCommand.Connection = conn;
        }

        public SqlConnection Conn
        {
            get
            {
                return conn;
            }
            set
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    conn.Dispose();
                }
                conn = (SqlConnection)value;
                textCommand = new SqlCommand();
                textCommand.Connection = conn;
                textCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            }
        }

        public object QueryScalar(string query)
        {
            textCommand.CommandText = query;

            string qtype = query.Substring(0, 6).ToLower();

            if (qtype == "select")
                return textCommand.ExecuteScalar();

            return textCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

I know I shouldn't access the database from the test. I tried using mock objects but I don't think they can help here, because I cannot change `textCommand` from the outside of the class. I tried setting up an SQLite database and accessing it through SQL, but to no avail.

My question is: How can I unit test QueryScalar method?

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: You need to either see if `SqlCommand` has an interface you can implement, or use the adapter pattern. I would be more inclined to do the latter

Comment: You could use the `IDbCommand` and `IDbConnection` interfaces.

Comment: I think you want to change your constructor. Either require an `SqlConnection` rather than an `IDbConnection` or use the `IDbConnection` rather than cast to `SqlConnection`. the way things are your code is going to throw an exception if you don't give it an `SqlConnection` and you should avoid exceptions in constructors if you can

Comment: Thanks for such fast replies. Well the problem is I don't think I can alter the code of the class. If I could, everything would get much easier. Meanwhile, is there any possibility to test given code without changing the DBHelper class?

Comment: Why not use an ORM which does all that for you and exposes an interface you can mock to unit test your code? The ORM will greatly reduce the amount of database access code you need to write (you won't need to worry about Command and Connection objects) - I maintain one called [MicroLite](https://github.com/TrevorPilley/MicroLite) if you want to check it out - there are also plenty of others available

Comment: If you can't change this class, steer away from it by 180 degrees. Don't even bother testing it if you're not allowed to fix it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use something like this in your class...

```
private IScalarQuerier _scalarQueryer;

public DBHelper(IDbConnection connection, IScalarQuerier q)
{
    _scalarQuerier = q;
    conn = (SqlConnection)connection;
    textCommand = new SqlCommand();
    textCommand.Connection = conn;
}
```

... and then place the `QueryScalar` method in a separate class, where you can do / test whatever you want. Just make that class implement an interface `IScalarQuerier`, so you can pass it in to `DBHelper`.

Might not be exactly what you were looking for, but this should let you do what you need with the method you want to test.

*Sidenote:* When you then pass that class (or `IScalarQuerier`-implementation, to be precise) into `DBHelper`, you should simply assume that the querier has been tested outside the scope of `DBHelper`, and that it therefore can be trusted to work correctly.